# What is the point in a framework like slim3 of sending response body in small chunks?

Tags: slim, slim-3

I am reading [slim 3](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/application.html#slim-default-settings) docs and found that it does read/send the response body text in chunks of 4096 bytes:

> responseChunkSize Size of each chunk read from the Response body when
>   sending to the browser.  (Default: 4096)

What is the point of doing it so? Wouldn't it better to send the response body at once? Would this imply a small overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During sending response to client browser, content length of response body may or may not be available.

In both cases, `responseChunkSize` settings is used as number of bytes to read from body until it reaches end of file. If content length is known and it is less or equal than `responseChunkSize`, then it only takes one iteration to read body's content.

By reading and output response in smaller chunk, browser does not wait too long to get first byte. Reading big chunk is slower and may require larger memory consumption so browser will likely get first byte longer than smaller chunk.

Comment: Thank you, then... as soon as there are some bytes (at least 4096) of the response available they are sent immediately to the browser, right?

Comment: yes. See `App.php` source in method `respond()` to better undestand how it works.

Comment: I will, I didn't realize that the response can be sent prior it was fully available. Thank you.